# Logback not creating the output logging file while using vertx

Tags: java, logging, logback, vert.x

I am expecting a log file to get created in each of the runs. It is not happening
I have added logback core and log back classic . Added logback.xml in resource folder . Made sure resource folder in build path .
The output log file is not getting created . The pattern specified in the logback.xml is also not comming up .

No matter what i give i get the message as

19/06/22 22:58:32 INFO class name : Log  Message

```
<configuration debug="true">
        <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder >
                <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>/data/csrt/log_path/logFiles/logFile.log</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>/data/csrt/log_path/logFiles/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder >
                <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
    </configuration>


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.AbstractVerticle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;

//import io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory;





public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainVerticle.class);
```

Comment: The Thing is - The file doesnt get created at all . . 19/06/22 22:58:32 INFO class name : Log Message this is the console output pattern

Comment: Are you using -Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.vertx.core.logging.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory as start argument?

Comment: nope will try that and will keep u posted